# How to check blocking id's in sybase query execution ,

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am running some update scripts in a server. Normally that will run in 20 - 30 mins. But today its taking very long time , more than 2 hrs. Will there be any block , can anyone help me how to identify the process running in tat server, and why it is running slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sp_who` will show you the processes running on your system, the status of each process, and the spid for any blocking processes (along with other information).

You can also use `sp_who USERNAME` to show the processes from a specific user.

If you wan't more detailed information about what is going on in your server while you are running your query, you can use `sp_sysmon` to give you detailed statistics about the various actions (reads, writes, cache hits, network reads, disk access, etc.)

[`sp_sysmon` syntax](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1550/html/sprocs/X21209.htm)

[Performance and Tuning using `sp_sysmon`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00842.1502/html/spsysmon/title.htm)